# Passing a SAFEARRAY variant to vba from a c++ dll

Tags: c++, vba, matrix, dll, safearray

I have in a DLL the following code, which is supposed to take some input from a routine written in VBA, do some stuff with it, and return **two 2D-arrays** back (so a function is not really doable, besides, if I wanted to return an array containing the other two, I'd have to face code-optimization problems in VBA), which can be accessed from VBA.
Without further ado, the code looks like this:

```
void _stdcall MySub(VARIANT RealCo, VARIANT ImagCo, VARIANT RealCr, VARIANT ImagCr, ULONG PointsTheta, ULONG PointsPhi, double Res, VARIANT CoPol, VARIANT CrPol)
{

/* Do my stuff here, and at the end produces the following arrays */

CoPol.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
CrPol.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
sab2[1].lLbound = 0; sab2[1].cElements = 360;
sab2[0].lLbound = 0; sab2[0].cElements = 360;
CoPol.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab2);
CrPol.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab2);

/* Those arrays are then stuffed with data */

}
```

Which I call from VBA as follows:

```
Private Declare Sub MySub Lib "Mypath/MyFile.dll" ( _
        ByVal RealCo As Variant, _
        ByVal ImagCo As Variant, _
        ByVal RealCr As Variant, _
        ByVal ImagCr As Variant, _
        ByVal PointsTheta As Long, _
        ByVal PointsPhi As Long, _
        ByVal Res As Double, _
        ByVal CoPol As Variant, _
        ByVal CrPol As Variant)

Dim CoPol As Variant, CrPol As Variant

' [...]

MySub CVar(RealCo), CVar(ImagCo), CVar(RealCr), CVar(ImagCr), PointsTheta, PointsPhi, Resolution, CoPol, CrPol
```

`CVar`is because the input arrays `RealCo`, `RealCr`, `ImagCo`, `ImagCr` are actually `Single` type in VBA.

It works, but my problem is the following: as I move from the last `}` in C++ to VBA, the content of `CoPol` and `CrPol` (which are the two matrices I would like to use further in the VBA code) disappears.

Notice that I can actually debug the code and check that `CoPol` and `CrPol` do contain data. I tried to pass them to another subroutine in C++, and since it didn't work as well, I came out with the solution of passing them via **reference**:

```
void _stdcall MySub(VARIANT RealCo, VARIANT ImagCo, VARIANT RealCr, VARIANT ImagCr, ULONG PointsTheta, ULONG PointsPhi, double Res, VARIANT &CoPol, VARIANT &CrPol)
```

This solved my problem *inside C++* but not between C++ and VBA. I also tried giving back pointers to the VARIANTS, and calling the needed arrays `ByRef` and `As Long`, but it doesn't work (`CoPol` and `CrPol` are then in VBA just a `Long` number, which I can't work with).

What should I write in order to make VBA able to access the values inside the matrix built in C++?

EDIT: if you want to downvote, at least explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you free memory afterwards if its allocated by a single function call in C++?

I would have done it the other way; declared and dim'ed the arrays in VBA and then passed pointer to array data to your C++ function, which then fills it up with values.

(Btw, I think its __stdcall with two underscores.)

```
void __stdcall fillarray(const int n, double *out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        out[i] = i;
    }
}
```

And then

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub fillarray Lib "Mypath/MyFile.dll" (ByVal n As Long, ByRef out As Double)

Dim A() as Double
Redim A(1 to 100)
fillarray 100, A(1)   'A(1) first element pointing to data
```

Comment: Sorry about the _stdcall -> __stdcall , I'm still learning. First of all thanks a lot, you opened my mind with some very short inputs that were however very clear. I now see actual data in VBA.
I do have one small problem though: the `out` array is bidimensional, and if I use `double *out` and fill out as `out[i * columns + j]` I get lots of elements of `out` that are zeroes. If I instead work with `double **out` and fill it as `out[i][j]`, which would be ideal for me, I get a data write failure.

Comment: Hmm, `i*columns+j` approach should work.  You can try to cast `out` as 2-dim: `double (*newout)[N] = (double (*)[N])out;`, where N is width/number of columns, and then `newout[i][j]` etc.